# Magento 2: Admin Listing Submit Form with Values

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, forms, listing

I have below code.

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index.php**

```
protected function _construct() {
    $this->addButton('select', array(
        'before_html' => '<form name="frm" id="frm" method="post" action=""><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="' . $this->getFormKey() . '"/>',
        'label' => __('Select'),
        'type' => 'submit',
        'name' => 'select',
        'id' => 'select',
        'value' => 1,
        'after_html' => '</form>',
    ));
}
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Grid.php**

```
 protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $this->addColumn(
                    'id', [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'id',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'id',
                'values' => array(3,4),
                    ]
            );

    $this->addColumn(
                    'qty_succeed[]', [
                'header' => __('Qty'),
                'type' => 'input', // Change to Input
                'index' => 'qty_succeed',
                'editor' => 'text',
                    ]
            );          
 }
```

I'm not using `_prepareMassaction` function as I'm not able to achieve needed functionality.

When clicked on "Select" button it should pass all values in Array so I can validate in Controller.

**Question 1** How to add form on listing portion only? Because `_prepareMassaction` is not taking textbox values. It only takes checkbox values

**Question 2** How to select main checkbox as well from Listing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For both mass action and regular button you can use javascript to trigger a function, which can then collect whatever form values you want and submit them to server. This is the simplest way to go in this case.

Comment: But there is no Form within the listing portion. How to add form so it takes textbox value as well

Comment: To collect inputs values you don't need a form, all you need is something like: $('div.your_listing_class input[type=text]').each( function(){ return $(this).val() })

Comment: I need row wise things Checkbox with Texbox value so I can put on 'onclick' event of button